# Get Distinct Rows Where Value in Row is Count > 1?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

So far I have this

```
var GetSetRows = from DataRow dr in MyTable.Rows
    group dr by dr.Field<string>("SetNumber") into grp
    from rows in grp
    where grp.Count() > 1
    select rows;
```

and this works to return every row where the SetNumber is in another row.

How can I modify this to only return 1 row for each SetNumber with a Count > 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.First`:

```
var GetSetRows = from DataRow dr in MyTable.Rows
                 group dr by dr.Field<string>("SetNumber") into grp
                 where grp.Count() > 1
                 select grp.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var GetSetRows = MyTable.Rows.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SetNumber"))
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: This will return the first group where the count is > 1, wouldn't it? I think the OP wants to bring back the first row per group

Answer (score 1):

```
var GetSetRows = MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("SetNumber"))
                        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(g => g.First());
```